# Magento2 : How can to get product collection by sorting with stock status i.e Asc,Decs

Tags: magento2, product-sorting

I have all product collection but I want it sort/order_by by Stock Status.for out-of-stock.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to your class to filter out of stock product

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock
 */
protected $_stockFilter;
protected $collectionFactory;
```

on class constructor

```
 public function __construct(
    .....
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
     \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter
    .....
) {
     $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
     $this->_stockFilter = $stockFilter;
}
```

in your method add the following code

```
public function getProducts(){
..........
 $collection= $this->collectionFactory->create();
 $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
..........
}
```

here `$collection` is product collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method :-  `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock::addInStockFilterToCollection` like below.

Example:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection);
$this->stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```